# How can I stop Code Runner running certain languages?

Tags: python, vb.net, vscode-code-runner

I am a big fan of **Code Runner**, and I'd like to use it to run Visual Basic scripts, since there seems to be no VB runners out there. But, I already use and love Microsoft's Python extension, and that allows me to run Python. If I install both, when I click on the run button, it gives me a menu and I have to click through to the correct option. I am kind of impatient and can't allow for that time loss.

Can I disable Code Runner's button for Python, but keep it for other languages?

Many thanks for you time.

Comment: You probably mean VB.Net instead of VBA.

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet located at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner, under "Besides, you could set the default language to run:"? Maybe that will cause the default language to run even when it can't deduce the correct option itself.

Comment: tHANK YOU. Sorry, CAPS LOCk was on.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, sorry.

Comment: @BigBen, however VB.NET is Visual Basic for Applications, but just as part of the .NET framework

Comment: @SamTheProgrammer not really. They're very different.

Comment: ok. I will yield